# Cycling plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to make it so plots made on matplotlib will cycle like a movie? If I have 12 different plots and having it show the first for 10 seconds, then the next and so on, then repeating after the last one? I would like to do this as an alternative to subplots due to the number of plots I want to show.

Comment: matplotlib has an `animation` module, take a look at this example: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, Using animation module with `repeat = True` and by modifying the `interval` argument to control the time between plots.

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()#


data_, = plot([], [])


def data_gen():
    while i < NUMBER_OF_PLOTS:
        '''
         make your instance of X data in a list called YOUR_X_DATA
         and your Y data in a list called YOUR_Y_DATA
         and iterate along it.
        '''
        yield YOUR_X_DATA[i], YOUR_Y_DATA[i]
        i+=1

def run(data):                
    data_.set_data(data[0], data[1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig , run, data_gen, interval=100,repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

**OR** using `time.sleep(10)` and `plt.close(fig)` this way

```
import time 

# suppose you have fig1, fi2, fig 3 etc. 

while(True):

   time.sleep(10)
   plt.close(fig1)

   # import the next plot
   time.sleep(10)
   plt.close(fig2)


   # import the next plot

   time.sleep(10)
   plt.close(fig3)
```

Comment: This should work. Would it be possible to make it so it changes everytime someone clicks a mouse or presses space?

Comment: you mean ""go to the next graph" by "change"?

Comment: I'm also still a little confused on your first example. Where do I put the different plots I want to be shown?

Comment: @greenthumbtack take alook to the comment I added. sorry

Comment: So YOUR_X_DATA is a list of lists of my data for the different plots?

Comment: @greenthumbtack exactly! and by the way you can accept the answer if it was useful for you

Comment: I was going to! I was just making sure to get it to work first

Comment: ehh, I'm running into a few errors but I think they're on my side. I also have to run for now so I'm going to look at it again later. I'll get back to you if I have other problems